# Alamofire 4.1.0 warnings

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am using alamofire 4.1.0, xcode 8.1 and swift 3.0.1 and I am getting this warnings in request respones.[image]

On alamofire github was said this will be fixed with the 4.1.0 release but the warnings are still there even after update

the`as Any` fix works but its not mentioned in the documentation

I got this warning after updating to xcode 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not specifically Alamofire, it's an Xcode warning. It happens when you try to `print` an optional value.